# Is this an appropriate place to ask questions about how to freely advertise my non-commercial Wikia website?

Tags: discussion

I've been working on a Wikia website of mine for the past several months and I want to know how to draw a bigger group of visitors to my Wiki without paying for it. This Wikia site is free with no intention of making money off people, rather our purpose is to provide free educational information. So I'd like to know if this is an appropriate place to ask how I could do this or whether this would be labelled as off-topic, or too subjective (i.e., subject to opinion that could make the question a breading ground for argument or otherwise non-constructive conversation).

Answer (score 2):

Specific questions about advertising a website are on topic here.

There could be some problems with your particular questions depending on how you ask it.  Specifically:

- Questions that ask for a list of recommendations don't play well with the voting system.  When those recommendations are for off-site resources such as "free places to advertise", they also tend to attract answers from spammers.  We would close any list of recommendation question.
- "How to advertise a website" is a topic that could fill a book.   We only accept questions here that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

You are welcome to ask you question but keep those points in mind.   If we close your question for any reason, feel free to edit it it and we will evaluate it again.